# Regex pattern for 'minimum of 5 characters' for an HTML form

Tags: html, regex, validation

I am just using HTML forms for the first time and I want to use the new pattern attribute. This is a regular expression (which I haven't used before) so I am a bit lost. The basic rule I want is 'minimum 5 of any characters'

I have tried:

```
pattern="([0-9][A-Z]){5}"
```

but this doesn't work, so I am obviously missing something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The basic rule I want is 'minimum 5 of any characters'

```
.{5,}
```

This will match any character (except `\n`) at least 5 times.

Answer (score -1):

Use this, instead: `[0-9a-zA-Z]{5,}`

Comment: Not good. If I type é, (, or ^ it won't work and maybe that's something you don't want. The question says "any characters".